# kaminari pagination on custom url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I have a case on url that generated by kaminari `paginate` as the url depends on a condition. Here is my routes

```
concern :search do
  scope '/search', as: :search do
    get '/', to: 'users#search'
    get '/schedule/:id', to: 'schedules#doctor', as: :schedule
  end
end

concerns :search

scope :dashboard, as: :dashboard do
  concerns :search
end
```

As you can see, the `:search` is accessible through `/search` and `/dashboard/search`. The problem is, `paginate @doctors` gives `/search` which basically will goes to `search_path` even though I'm on `dashboard_search_path` (it should gives `/dashboard/search` path).

My question is, how can I pass a custom path to `paginate`? I'd like `paginate` to use `search_path` when I open `/search` and use `dashboard_search_path` when I'm on `/dashboard/search/path`.

You don't have to provide how to decide `/search` or `/dashboard/search`, I just need to know how to pass it to `paginate` as an argument. Ta

Answer (score 2):

Kaminari accepts parameters for paginate, one of them is `params` for the links. It works the same as `url_for` in rails. Didn't test it, but try for dashboard pages, should work.

```
paginate @doctors, params: { script_name: "/dashboard" }
```

From docs for `url_for`:

> :script_name - specifies application path relative to domain root. If provided, prepends application path.

Comment: This adds `"/dashboard"` to the existing base URL. If you're looking to change the base URL itself, this may not work.

Answer (score 0):

use `url` param for paginate and have your custom code in proc which will define the final url:

```
paginate @doctors, url: proc{|page| some_condition ? search_path : dashboard_search_path}
```

Comment: Tested in kaminari '1.2.2', the `url` argument is ignored. The solution with the `params` argument works.